# Fix Looping when using include In Linq EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Is there any way to fix looping issue in LINQ with EF6 in my case there was three classes as below:

**First : Staff Class:**

```
public class staff
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  Name {get;set;}
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Classes { get; set; }    
}
```

**Second: Classes Class:**

```
public class Classes {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StaffClass> StaffClasses { get; set; }
 }
```

**Third : StaffClass Class:**

```
public class StaffClass{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public virtual  Staff  Staffs { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Classes { get; set; }
}
```

When Trying to get data from Context like

```
Context.Staffs.Include(s => s.StaffClass.Select(f=>f.Classes))
```

The result for above query :

```
[{
"Id": 4,
"Name": "Teacher",
"StaffClass": [{
    "ID": 13,
    "ClassId": 6,
    "Classes": {
        "Id": 6,
        "ClassName": "S1",
        "StaffClasses": [{
            "ID": 27,
            "ClassId": 6
        }, {
            "ID": 33,
            "ClassId": 6
        }]
    }
    }]
}]
```

the expected result to return only staff and classes without load staffclasses again inside the classess

I try set lazy loading to `false` in `Context`

```
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

but I get the same result

Comment: Why does it matter to you that it is there? Explain to use the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't need the staffclass to be loaded again in the classes  class

Comment: I understand that. But **why**? If you left the code as is, would something break (and if so, what)? What is the problem caused by the existence of the staffclass under class? For example, are you serialising the data to JSON and returning it - and thus you don't want it to appear there? Or something else?

Comment: it takes lot of time to return the results that is why i want to prevent the children to load again

Comment: If you download and run a trial of https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof , what is the SQL being generated?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this may be an issue of JSON serialization:

Try this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings
      .ReferenceLoopHandling = 
       Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

This will ignore the reference pointing back to the object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,.
but there was no problem when serializing the result all thing work fine but i don't need to loop and include all child again .

Comment: How is that JSON returned?

Comment: From API Controller

Comment: Then, by adding those line in `WebApiConfig.cs` file should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add JsonIgnore attribute to property:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public virtual Class Classes { get; set; }
```

Comment: The downside of this method is that now it's impossible to get a staff with Classes. In general I don't think that serialization concerns belong in the data layer. (Single responsibility principle).