# EF6 Include one but return Object of infinite level

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using EF6 and faced a situation where the objects contained each other infinitely.

I use DB first, it generates two 1-n relation classes as below:

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual User Cashier { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

I call to get data from DB:

```
var orders = OrderService.GetAll()
            .Include(m => m.Branch)
            .Include(m => m.Customer)
            .Include(m => m.Payments)
            .Include(m => m.Seller)
            .Include(m => m.User)
            .Include(m => m.InvoiceOrderSurcharges)
            .Include(m => m.DeliveryInfoes)
            .Include(m => m.DeliveryPackages)
            .Include(m => m.SaleChannel)
            .Include(m => m.Invoices)
            .Include(m => m.OrderPromotions)
            .Include(m => m.InvoiceWarranties);


var lsDtoId = await orders.Select(i => i.Id).Take(req).ToListAsyncWithNoLock();//Get top 15 Id
lsTemp = ls.Where(i => lsDtoId.Contains(i.Id));

var result = await lsTemp.ToListAsync();
```

But the orders object seems to contain infinite child objects.

result.Cashier.Orders.ToList()[0].Cashier......Orders.ToList()[0] has data.

This leads to when I convert the object to json to return the API, I get an error.

Why do I include only one child object but return infinite levels. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit question:**

***How to prevent reference loops when using include in linq EF6?***

**Update:**

When I use @Svyatoslav Danyliv's method (add AsNoTracking), the result.Cashier will be null (I'm very happy). However, result.Branch.Orders.ToList()[0].Branch.Orders.... continues to be a reference loops.

I turned off the proxy but still not working.

```
OrderService.DisableProxy();
public void DisableProxy()
{
     Db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: There are many questions on this topic, please look for questions on preventing reference loops in JSON serialization.

Comment: you can prevent with `ReferenceHandler.Preserve` for json. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: Add `AsNoTracking` to the query, it should preserve navigation properties fixup.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv: Thanks very much. I have applied and succeeded. But I don't know why adding AsNoTracking results in ignoring "reference loop/ circular reference". Can you explain in detail?

Comment: This was the same question five years ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44799341/fix-looping-when-using-include-in-linq-ef,  but still unresolved ;(

Answer (score 1):

It's not that orders contains infinite child objects but rather that you have a reference loop/ circular reference. `Order` has a reference to `User` and `User` has a reference to `Order`. This can't be serialised into JSON with with the typical default configuration.

If you are using the .Net JSON serializer then you can use the `ReferenceHandler.Preserve` option as mentioned by Okan Karadag:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-preserve-references?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Update:

Another solution which might be better when using third party libraries would be simply to not serialise the property causing the problem and send it through separate. 3rd party libraries tend to provide a JSON ignore attribute to prevent a property from being serialised.

In your scenario, you would put an ignore attribute above `Orders` in `User` and would need to have get the list of orders for each user separately and serialize them but this would probably require some reworking of your code/design.

Adding a link to some documentation on the JSON ignore attribute for your reference: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Current project is using a 3rd library to return default Json string. I don't want to edit too much because I'm worried about its effects.
Is there a way to counter the "reference loop/ circular reference"?

Comment: Updated answer with another solution but it may be a bit painful - hard to see without having a wider view of your code.

Comment: Just to clarify the issue of the circular reference: order has a reference to user and user has a reference to a list of users. If you were debugging the code and observed a particular order, you would be able to look at its user - then for that user you would be able to see its list of orders, if you picked an order you would be able to see it's user. This would go on endlessly. This cannot be serialised into JSON. A solution is to add the JSON ignore attribute to every property that causes circular references e.g. ```Branch.Orders```.